# Deleted Discussions are no longer shown with deleted-color background

Tags: bug, status-completed, discussions-space

Deleted posts normally have a different background color as part of visually distinguishing that they are deleted. This used to also be the case for deleted Discussions. Unfortunately, deleted discussions are no longer shown with a deleted-color background.

[Example deleted Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78081920) (link only works for Mod/staff; screenshot not included, so as to not further distribute the deleted content)

I've tested this in both Firefox and Chrome without any browser extensions or userscripts.

It appears the HTML attempts to apply the deleted-color background color with a `bg-red-100` class (one of the "normal" ways for SE to apply the deleted-color background on some elements), which applies `background-color: var(--red-100) !important;`, on the `<div>` which contains the `div#mainbar`, but it's ineffective. There are a variety of ways this can be resolved.

Comment: Huh, I get a _"Page not found"_ on that link. Are deleted discussions not visible to normal (trusted) users?

Comment: @Cerbrus correct. it's still just MVP

Comment: Ugh SE reinventing the wheel...

Comment: @Cerbrus nor can users edit discussions. They can't really be trusted with that, either.

Comment: Makes sense that the normal curation privileges do not apply here. "Discussions" is fundamentally different. Wiki-style editing may not be even logical in this context, nor seeing deleted "posts". I dislike "discussions" very much, but I think it may be correct the this part of the site does not behave like Q&A, or has the same set of tools available.

Comment: 'screenshot not included, so as to not further distribute the deleted content' Could you not just take a screen shot and pixelate, blur or otherwise obfuscate the content in an image editor? Just saying.

Comment: I mean, taking a screenshot of some blured text on a background is hardly indicating anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

We have fixed this bug, the red background should now be visible on all deleted Discussion posts (to anyone who can see those posts including mods, post authors, staff). We have also fixed a related issue, which was that the red background color disappeared if the screen width was 981px or larger.